# Assign list to a single pandas dataframe column when using apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in pandas dataframe in the format : "A,B,C,D" and I would like to split store it as a list instead [A,B,C,D]. I am using the below code to do the conversion but I keep getting the following error : ***ValueError: Shape of passed values is (58110, 3), indices imply (58110, 36)***

```
def convert_list(df):    
  return  df['textlist'].split(',')


df['newcol']= df.apply(lambda x:convert_list(x),axis=1)
```

Comment: Do you need `df['newcol'] = df['textlist'].str.split(',')` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['newcol'] = df['textlist'].str.split(',')
```

Comment: Thanks! i missed the obvious answer

Answer (score 1):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(textlist=['a,b,c,d']))

df

  textlist
0  a,b,c,d
```

---

@jezrael's answer is perfect!  No need to do anything different.

```
df.assign(newcol=df.textlist.str.split(','))
```

However, your function (with one slight mod) would have worked like this:

```
def convert_list(df):    
    return  df['textlist'].str.split(',')

df.assign(newcol=convert_list)

  textlist        newcol
0  a,b,c,d  [a, b, c, d]
```

And you could also use numpy's `np.core.defchararray.split`

```
df.assign(newcol=np.core.defchararray.split(df.textlist.values.astype(str), ','))

  textlist        newcol
0  a,b,c,d  [a, b, c, d]
```